# How to efficiently split each row into test and train subsets using R?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, training-data

I have a data table that provides the length and composition of given vectors
for example:

```
set.seed(1)

dt = data.table(length = c(100, 150),
                n_A = c(30, 30), 
                n_B = c(20, 100), 
                n_C = c(50, 20))
```

I need to randomly split each vector into two subsets with 80% and 20% of observations respectively. I can currently do this using a for loop. For example:

```
dt_80_list <- list() # create output lists
dt_20_list <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(dt)){ # for each row in the data.table
  
  sample_vec <- sample( c(   rep("A", dt$n_A[i]), # create a randomised vector with the given nnumber of each component. 
                             rep("B", dt$n_B[i]),
                             rep("C", dt$n_C[i]) ) )
  
  sample_vec_80 <- sample_vec[1:floor(length(sample_vec)*0.8)] # subset 80% of the vector
  
  dt_80_list[[i]] <- data.table(   length = length(sample_vec_80), # count the number of each component in the subset and output to list
                         n_A = length(sample_vec_80[which(sample_vec_80 == "A")]),
                         n_B = length(sample_vec_80[which(sample_vec_80 == "B")]),
                         n_C = length(sample_vec_80[which(sample_vec_80 == "C")])
  )
  
  dt_20_list[[i]] <- data.table(   length = dt$length[i] - dt_80_list[[i]]$length, # subtract the number of each component in the 80% to identify the number in the 20%
                         n_A = dt$n_A[i] - dt_80_list[[i]]$n_A,
                         n_B = dt$n_B[i] - dt_80_list[[i]]$n_B,
                         n_C = dt$n_C[i] - dt_80_list[[i]]$n_C
  )
}
dt_80 <- do.call("rbind", dt_80_list) # collapse lists to output data.tables
dt_20 <- do.call("rbind", dt_20_list)
```

However, the dataset I need to apply this to is very large, and this is too slow. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could improve performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I assumed your dataset consists of many more rows (but only a few colums).)

Here's a version I came up with, with mainly three changes

- use `.N` and `by=` to count the number of "A","B","C" drawn in each row
- use the size argument in `sample`
- join the original `dt` and `dt_80` to calculate `dt_20` without a for-loop

```
## draw training data
dt_80 <- dcast(
      dt[,row:=1:nrow(dt)
       ][, .(draw=sample(c(rep("A80",n_A),
                           rep("B80",n_B),
                           rep("C80",n_C)),
                         size=.8*length)  )
         , by=row
       ][,.N,
         by=.(row,draw)],
  row~draw,value.var="N")[,length80:=A80+B80+C80]

## draw test data
dt_20 <- dt[dt_80,
            .(A20=n_A-A80,
              B20=n_B-B80,
              C20=n_C-C80),on="row"][,length20:=A20+B20+C20]
```

There is probably still room for optimization, but I hope it already helps :)

**EDIT**

Here I add my initial first idea, I did not post this because the code above is much faster. But this one might be more memory-efficient which seems crucial in your case. So, even if you already have a working solution, this might be of interest...

```
library(data.table)
library(Rfast)

## add row numbers
dt[,row:=1:nrow(dt)]

## sampling function
sampfunc <- function(n_A,n_B,n_C){ 
  draw <- sample(c(rep("A80",n_A),
                   rep("B80",n_B),
                   rep("C80",n_C)),
                 size=.8*(n_A+n_B+n_C))
  out <- Rfast::Table(draw)
  return(as.list(out))
}

## draw training data
dt_80 <- dt[,sampfunc(n_A,n_B,n_C),by=row]
```

Comment: Frustratingly, while this provides a considerable improvement on the example dataset, my dataset is too large and the vector memory is being exhausted.

Comment: Hmm .. this might be a new question on its own. 

Could you give more insight on your error?
What exactly is large about your data, the number of rows or the values in the `length` column (or both)?
...rerunning the code with `verbose=TRUE` within each data.table might give further clues ...

Comment: Both the size of the values in the length column, and the number of rows are very large. I have, however, managed to adapt your code to work by splitting the data.table into a list of smaller data.tables and looping through to avoid using too much memory. Im sure there is a more efficient way than this, but it is fast enough for me now, and much faster than what I was previously trying. Thanks so much for your help. :)

Comment: Rfast::Table is slow because argument name is set to TRUE by default. The name mechanism unfortunately is slow in R. Use Table with name set to FALSE and the runtime will be reduced about 20 times.